# No route matches [DELETE]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I don't know what is it happened with my app. I have some controllers that are working perfectly but this one not.

my sylabus_controller.rb

```
   # encoding: utf-8
    module Admin
      class SylabusController < BaseController

def destroy
      @sylabu = @topic.sylabus.find(params[:sylabus])
      @sylabu.destroy
     redirect_to  admin_course_topic_sylabu_path(@course, @topic), notice: 'Sylabus deleted'

    end
```

my /views/admin/sylabus/index.html.rb

```
<% @sylabu.each do |syla| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= syla.mupet_code %></td>
                <td><%= syla.name %></td>

              <td style="width:155px">
         <%= link_to '<i class="icon-pencil"></i>'.html_safe, edit_admin_course_topic_sylabus_path(@course,
                                                                                                        @topic,
                                                                                                        syla),
                            class: 'btn' %>
                    <%= link_to '<i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>'.html_safe, [:admin, @course, @topic, syla], class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

                <%= link_to '<i class="icon-eye-open"></i>'.html_safe, [:admin, @course, @topic, syla],
                            class: 'btn' %>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
```

The target web is in the button delete is localhost:3000/admin/courses/1/topics/2/sylabus.8 and with the following error message

```
Routing Error

No route matches [DELETE] "/admin/courses/1/topics/2/sylabus.8"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

If I execute rake routes from my console

```
                          POST   /admin/courses/:course_id/topics/:topic_id/sylabus(.:format)                             admin/sylabus#create
 new_admin_course_topic_sylabu GET    /admin/courses/:course_id/topics/:topic_id/sylabus/new(.:format)                         admin/sylabus#new
edit_admin_course_topic_sylabu GET    /admin/courses/:course_id/topics/:topic_id/sylabus/:id/edit(.:format)                    admin/sylabus#edit
     admin_course_topic_sylabu GET    /admin/courses/:course_id/topics/:topic_id/sylabus/:id(.:format)                         admin/sylabus#show
                               PUT    /admin/courses/:course_id/topics/:topic_id/sylabus/:id(.:format)                         admin/sylabus#update
                               DELETE /admin/courses/:course_id/topics/:topic_id/sylabus/:id(.:format)                         admin/sylabus#destroy
```

Sincerely I don't know from the error is coming because it's a copy and paste from other controllers that are working perfectly.

Well thank you very much for your answers.

Have a great day

Comment: It was supposed to be `/8`, not `.8` on the end of the generated url. He is taking the `syla` as format, not as object. Most likely you can't construct the URL like this (although I don't know how)

Answer (score 1):

By the `.8` suffix it looks like it's using the `index` path instead of the `delete` path. Try being explicit

```
<%= link_to 'blah'.html_safe, admin_course_topic_sylabus_path(:admin, @course, @topic, syla), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: I still think that it is a parameter order problem, or something.

Comment: it was without the (:admin